# Custom multiplication and numpy

Tags: python, numpy

Suppose I have my own multiplication between two Python objects `a` and `b`, let's call it `my_multiplication(a, b)`.

How can I perform a matrix multiplication using numpy where `my_multiplication` is performed instead of the usual `*`? Is that even possible?

**Addendum:** Would I still benefit from numpy's speed then?

Comment: So you want to overwrite the operation of * as my_multiplication? or you just want to be able to use your my_multiplication

Comment: I just want to use it and keep `*` as it was.

Comment: just out of curiosity, why would you need to overwrite * ? Why not just use the function as a separate function

Comment: I don't want to overwrite `*`. That's the whole point.

Comment: However, I want to benefit from numpy's fast matrix multiplication.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [np.vectorise](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.vectorize.html) on your function to get your custom multiplication function use all the usual numpy features such as broadcasting.

```
def my_multiplication(a, b):
    #your code that works on multiplying 2 numbers
    return c
v_my_multiplication = np.vectorize(my_multiplication)
v_my_multiplication([1, 2, 3], [1, 6])

#Will now work for np.array instead of just 2 numbers and utilize the broadcasting and vectorized implementation benefits that numpy has to offer.
```

Comment: Thank you very much. That looks quite promising. I am quite new to numpy. So, how can I now recover the matrix multiplication from this vectorized function?

Comment: just call the function like any other function. f(x,y) as the last line of my code. The np.vectorise takes a function as an input and returns a vectorized function that can then be named something else and called instead of the original function.

Comment: No, I already got that. But `v_my_multiplication(2d_arr1, 2d_arr2)` does not yield a matix multplication rather than something else (entry-wise multplication?).

Comment: By the way, your example won't work because the dimensions of your arrays don't fit.

Comment: Depends on the function. Broadcasting will with when a function is vectorised as well.

Comment: I am sorry. I do not understand what you are referring to.

Comment: if your multiplication function is supposed to work on multiplying a 3,1 array (as in my example) with a scaler.. then this will work by broadcasting it to a 3X2 so that it can multiple a 2X1 and give a 3X2 as a result (first 3x1 multiplies the first element while a copy of the 3x1 multiplies the second). I encourage you to check this out - https://machinelearningmastery.com/broadcasting-with-numpy-arrays/

Comment: I don't have the feeling that the link you've posted helps me for my particular problem. I want to realize the usual matrix multplication in the __mathematical__ sense, where the `*` operator is replaced by another kind of multiplication. Nothing like that is described in the link above. If I am not mistaken, the usual matrix multiplication of 2d-arrays in numpy is realized by `dot` or `matmul`. That is what I am looking for.

Comment: Sorry i am a little confused about your last comment. Multiplication has different definitions, its an outer operation in a linear algebra context and so you can just directly use a ```np.dot``` for it. But you need to share in your post what your ```my_multiplication actually``` is. I suggest that irrespective of what that function is .. if you want it to behave 'like' a dot product or a numpy function which operates over ndarrays / matrices, you can use ```np.vectorise```. Isnt that what the question was, correct me if i am wrong.

Comment: Answer me this - 1. You have your 'own' multiplication which isnt like standard multiplication right? 2. You DONT want ```np.dot``` or element wise multiplication ```np.multiply``` right? 3. You want it to work on n dimensional vectors instead of just 2 numbers just the way numpy functions work right?

Comment: If the answers to the above are Yes, Yes and Yes. Then my answer should solve the problem for you.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/218708/discussion-between-youngmath-and-akshay-sehgal).

Answer (score 0):

Try the `numpy.dot` or the `x.dot(y)`. See the documentation [here](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.dot.html)

**Example**

```
import numpy as np
x = np.arange(12).reshape((3,4))
y = np.arange(4)
print(x,"\n\n",y,"\n")
print (np.dot(x,y))

[[ 0  1  2  3]
 [ 4  5  6  7]
 [ 8  9 10 11]] 

 [0 1 2 3] 

[14 38 62]
```